# Avoiding merge problems when sharing solution between Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

When sharing a solution between Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio, changes to solution/projects leads to unexpected results. The source text of the *.sln/*.project files has unexpected modifications, e.g.

- UUIDs changed from lower to upper case
- Reordering of lines in the .sln file
- Changed "ToolsVersion"
- Changed "Visual Studio" version
- Other changes, like changing line break, changed "true" to "True", ...

This e.g. happens when changing the startup project, adding referenced projects, building the solution.

These changes lead to a "commit ping pong" between Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio users, and make merging harder. We experienced this problem with Xamarin Studio 5.5.4 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. The https://github.com/perpetual-mobile/SharingXamarinSolution repository contains examples. The http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/95851 thread also describes this issue.

How can this problem be avoided? Is it possible to prevent this from happening when using only Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio? Or do we need an additional tool (like e.g. [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/))?

Comment: One workaround is to create a script that produces Xamarin-specific solution and project files, and run it after every checkout. As for getting modifications back into the VS versions, the script would need to operate in reverse. Any volunteers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One answer is to wait for version 6 of Xamarin Studio.

According to the [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25825) filed by Stephan Palmer, the issues raised above have been resolved in that version.

Comment: Anyone has an idea, when version6 will be released? Currently we have Alpha 3.

Comment: Since posting this question, my team has moved to mac only development. Due to this, I unfortunately don't have experience sharing project files between Visual Studio and newer Xamarin Studio versions. However, as @chue-x answered, the corresponding bug report was resolved fixed for Xamarin Studio 6. The currently released stable version of Xamarin Studio is 6.1.2.44. Also interesting: The recently announced [Visual Studio for Mac](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/11/16/visual-studio-for-mac/) explicitly supports sharing of project files with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing the same behavior if the project starts in Xamarin for Visual Studio versus Xamarin standalone versions?

The fastest workaround that comes to mind would be to use vcproj2cmake (uses Ruby)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vcproj2cmake/

and use CMake scripting.

I highly recommend contacting Kitware and asking them for cross-compiling assistance - - they may already have a CMake script to resolve this issue since Xamarin is so popular.

kitware@kitware.com

Hope that helps, 
               ClaireW